# X-ray tubes: why are inner shell electrons are inonized rather then excited?

Tags: electrons, x-rays

I have been reading (e.g. [here](https://xraykamarul.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/lecture3.pdf)) about how in an x-ray tube outer electrons can be excited and on returning to the ground state emit infrared radiation which heats up the sample. I have however never heard of the process occurring of inner shell electrons been excited rather then ionized in an x-ray tube (or for that matter during the absorption of x-rays in a filter). Does this processes occur? If is it much less pronounced compared to ionization and compared to the same effect in outer electrons?

Comment: Never given it much thought, but my first inclination is to ask how the phase space for excitation compares to that for ionization.

Comment: @dmckee good point, but if this was the case I would expect a similar prominence of ionization in outer-electrons over excitation. I could be wrong but from what I have read this is not the case.

Comment: Hmm. Are the photons assumed to be absorbed or scattered? (Or is there no assumption?) In the scattering case you would seem to be right, but in the former case the strength of the bonding to the nucleus controls how energetic a photon may be absorbed without violating the conservation of four-momentum (keep in mind that a scattering experiment effectively measures a particular momentum for the effected constituent).

Comment: That link does not mention infrared as far as I can see. As to the other question, look at "white lines" in NEXAFS (near-edge x-ray absorption spectroscopy).

Comment: @Pieter Ok thanks. For future reference (for me or anyone else who stumbles on this question) *Applications of Physical Methods to Inorganic and Bioinorganic Chemistry* By Robert A. Scott has a nice explanation of  NEXAFS on page 193.